# pandas bug with empty DataFrame?

Tags: numpy, pandas

Here is my code snippet:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.12.0'
>>> np.__version__
'1.6.2'
>>> pd.DataFrame(None,columns=['x'])['x'].values + np.min([0.5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.float64'
```

I'm making a sum between an empty array and a scalar. Notice that if I construct the array with `np.array` or with `pd.Series` it works fine (the result is an empty array). The same is true if I replace `np.min([0.5])` (which is a `np.float64`) with a float: `0.5`.

I find this very strange! Of course I can easily patch my program, but I think this is a bug of pandas, isn't it?

**addendum** is it correct to initialize `pd.DataFrame` with `None` to get an empty DataFrame with given columns?

Comment: This doesn't occur in pandas 1.7.2.

Comment: @Justin you mean numpy 1.7.2?

Comment: I sure did! numpy 1.7.2 and pandas 0.12.0.  And as for the addendum, you don't need none:  `pd.DataFrame(columns=['x'])` is plenty.

Comment: Doesn't happen with numpy 1.7.1 and pandas 0.12.0 either.

Comment: @Justin: but I want to initialize `pd.DataFrame` with a list which might be empty. So I do `pd.DataFrame(mylist or None,columns=[...])`

Comment: I've upgraded my numpy to 1.8.0 and the problem has solved... thanks!

Comment: Ah, I think I'd use what you've written there.